# Building a Rand StdGen Int

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand what the following type signature means.

`f :: Int -> Rand StdGen Int`

So `Rand` is a `newtype`, says the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/src/Control-Monad-Random.html).

```
-- | A basic random monad.
newtype Rand g a = Rand (RandT g Identity a)
    deriving (Functor, Monad, MonadRandom, MonadSplit g)
```

I don't know what the right-hand side involves, but let me continue.

Its kind is:

```
ghci> :k Rand
Rand :: * -> * -> *
```

I believe that `StdGen` is an instance of `RandomGen`,  which is a type class.

The [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.0.3/docs/System-Random.html#t:RandomGen) note:

```
data StdGen

The StdGen instance of RandomGen has a genRange of at least 30 bits.
```

**EDIT**:
Per [@user5402](https://stackoverflow.com/users/866915/user5402)'s comment, `Rand StdGen Int` is a concrete type.

```
ghci> :k Rand StdGen Int
Rand StdGen Int :: *
```

However, I'm not sure what it means to make a `Rand StdGen Int`.

Please provide an implementation of the above function, `f`.

Comment: `Rand StdGen Int` is a concrete type.

Comment: Thanks, user5402. Could you please consider my question about what a `Rand StdGen Int` is? Or, perhaps you could show me an implementation, please?

Comment: I've edited slightly your question - the `Source` is just a hyperlink which displays the source code for the definition of StdGen.

Comment: `Rand StdGen` is a `Monad`, and you haven't specified what `f` should *do*, so the simplest implementation is something like `const (return 0)`.

Comment: @user2407038 - why did you add the `const`? I was able to simply do: `let x = return 0 :: Rand StdGen Int`

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `m` is a value of type `Rand StdGen Int`. Then some things we can do with it are:

```
-- use it to generate a random Int
evalRandIO m >>= print   -- generate a random Int and print it

-- create a generator for a pair of random Ints
twoRandInts :: Rand StdGen (Int,Int)
twoRandInts = do a <- m; b <- m; return (a,b)
```

You can think of it as a (monadic) procedure which creates a random Int using a `StdGen` seed. Note that `m` by itself is just the procedure. To "run" the procedure you need to use a function like `evalRandIO`.

To answer your question about what a function like `f` would look like, consider this (taken from the Example section of the MonadRandom docs) [(link)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.3.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html#g:2):

```
-- produce a random number between 1 and n
f :: Int -> Rand StdGen Int
f n = getRandomR (1,n)
```

Another example:

```
-- produce a random multiple of n
g :: Int -> Rand StdGen Int
g n = fmap (*n) getRandom
```

To create `Rand g a` values, use the `getRandom*` methods defined in Control.Monad.Random.Class.

Comment: **edit**: I originally asked about constructing a new `Rand StdGen` directly, but then recalled what @Ørjan had written: `However, you cannot use this directly to construct your f, because Control.Monad.Random doesn't export the newtype constructors` in this below answer.

Comment: Interesting. How does ```getRandom``` return a random number **without** a generator?

Comment: `getRandom` can't produce a random value by itself - you need to "run" it with an evalRand* or runRand* function, and if you look at the signatures of those functions you see that you need to either supply a generator or, in the evalRandIO, a generator will be created for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the rabbit hole all the way down. You have

```
newtype Rand g a = Rand (RandT g Identity a)
```

so to build a `Rand StdGen Int` you need a `RandT StdGen Identity Int`. And then (leaving out some noise):

```
newtype RandT g m a = RandT (StateT g m a)
```

so for *that*, you need a `StateT StdGen Identity Int`. And then

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT {runStateT :: s -> m (a, s)}
```

so what you need is `StdGen -> Identity (Int, StdGen)`. Now because

```
newtype Identity a = Identity {runIdentity :: a}
```

that is essentially the same as `StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)`.

So `Rand StdGen Int` is essentially a several levels deep `newtype` wrapping around a function that takes a `StdGen`, and produces an `Int` result and a new `StdGen`.

However, you cannot use this directly to construct your `f`, because `Control.Monad.Random` *doesn't export* the newtype constructors, so this representation is hidden to users of the library. Instead you need to use the API functions which it *does* provide. One possibility:

```
f :: Int -> Rand StdGen Int
f n = getRandomR (0,n)
```